# It is possible to add 2 conditions in the Fiddler2 autoresponder "if" field?

Tags: fiddler

I have custom rules (CustomRules.js) from where I can do anything, but... when I use the Autoreponder I can't add a double codition like `this but not this` in same clause.

I really think that this cannot be done by design of that feature, but wanna be sure before leaving it.

Note: I know I can add two conditions, one per field/rule, what I want is to use any kind of operator like `URLWithBody` that has 2 strings on it. I suspect that is a special function accepting 2 arguments.

Im not english, not that few words may be misstyped.